# Laravel not sending email to Gmail/Hotmail if run from Scheduler

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-scheduler

I have a very weird situation sending emails from my Laravel project.

1 - Sending email to ANY address from a test function in HomeController **works**.

2 - Sending email to addresses that belong to any of my domains in the same hosting, run from Scheduler (php artisan schedule:run) **works**.

3 - Sending email to hotmail/gmail addresses, run from Scheduler **does not work**.

The test function in HomeController is **exactly** the same as the function in the Scheduler. I put logs everywhere, so I am sure the Mail function in the Scheduler is being called, there are no error logs at all, it just never arrives.

My mail config is `smtp, port 587, tls encryption.`

Any ideas of what could be wrong in the scheduler for hotmail/gmail addresses?

**----------UPDATE---------**

I found a workaround here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/42-email-not-being-sent-when-using-artisan-command

It says to basically replace the $_domain variable in AbstractSmtpTransport.php file, since it uses 127.0.0.1 by default.

However, I'm not sure what IP this is supposed to be using. Would it be my shared hosting IP address?

Comment: did you check in the spam folder?

Comment: Yes I’m checking all folders.

Comment: sending  normal mail(without Scheduler) to gmail/hotmail working ?

Comment: Correct, it works without Scheduler.

Comment: have checked in the fail jobs?

Comment: What failed jobs? I’m not using Queues btw, it’s a simple Mail::raw with some text on it.